# How to send email to applicants in first stage; recruitment odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

I wanna send emails to applicants in the first stage of recruitment in Odoo 14. How can go about it using python?
Here's my code.

```
def job_applicant_acknowledgments(self):
    for rec in self:
        get_first_stage = self.env['hr.recruitment.stage'].search([
            '|',
            ('job_ids', '=', False),
            ('job_ids', '=', self.id)], order='sequence asc', limit=1)
        if self.partner_id and get_first_stage and not emai_sent:
                ctx = {}
                ctx['email_to'] = rec.partner_id.email
                # ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.user_id.email
                # ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.employee_id.work_email
                ctx['send_email'] = True
                ctx['partner_id'] = rec.partner_id.id
                template = self.env.ref(
                    'hr_recruitment_custom.job_applicant_acknowledgment')
                template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(
                    rec.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: CZoellner, I did sort it out, thank though. The problem is that it is doing fine in local but not in odoo.sh. The cron is not sending emails in odoo.sh but it is sending in my local system. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed.
This is the python code that sends an email to the applicant either when they apply for a position or if you create a position id recruitment, odoo.

```
 def job_applicant_acknowledgments(self):
        for rec in self:
            ctx = {}
            ctx['email_to'] = rec.partner_id.email
            ctx['email_from'] = self.env.user.user_id.email
            ctx['send_email'] = True
            ctx['partner_id'] = rec.partner_id.id
            template = self.env.ref('hr_recruitment_custom.job_applicant_acknowledgment')
            template.with_context(ctx).send_mail(
                rec.id, force_send=True, raise_exception=False)
```

The code I added:

```
    def job_applicant_acknowledgments_cron(self):
        partner_ids = self.env['hr.applicant'].search([('email_sent', '=', False)])
        for applicant in partner_ids:
            if applicant.email_sent is False:
                applicant.job_applicant_acknowledgments()
                applicant.email_sent = True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's a mistake in your `if`. You probably want to user `rec.partner_id` and not `self.partner_id`?

Comment: I have updated it still not working in odoo.sh.
What could I be missing?